# Remove a user or group assignment to an enterprise app using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to remove a user or group assignment to an enterprise app using Azure AD Graph or Microsoft Graph in C#.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by juunas is right, I just make some additions.

As you want to do this operation by c# code, so you can refer to my steps below:

**1.** Install two SDKs in your project.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Auth -IncludePrerelease
Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Beta -Version 0.14.0-preview
```

I referred to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation) about install SDKs, but I can't find `AppRoleAssignments` in `GraphServiceClient` class. So please install SDKs with the commands above.

**2.** Please refer to the code below:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Security;

namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("your client id")
            .WithTenantId("your tenantid")
            .Build();

            UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            string password = "your password";
            foreach (char c in password)
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);

            await graphClient.Users["user object id"].AppRoleAssignments["role assignment id"].Request().WithUsernamePassword("email account", securePassword).DeleteAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("----complete---");
        }
    }
}
```

The `role assignment id` in `AppRoleAssignments["role assignment id"]` above comes from the list query [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http): `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo/{id}`

**3.** Before running the c# code, we need to enable we have assign the delegated permission `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` to the app and enable the button shown as below screenshot.
[image]

**4.** After that, we can running the code and remove the user or group successfully.

**5.** By the way:

(1) The code I provided is for remove users assignment. If you want to remove group assignment, just modify the code as:

```
await graphClient.Groups["group object id"].AppRoleAssignments["role assignment id"].Request().WithUsernamePassword("email account", securePassword).DeleteAsync();
```

(2) You need to pay attention to the beta version of api as juunas mentioned.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks Hury.  Your answer is appreciated.  However, I don't want to use password here

Comment: I wanted to use client id and secret of a registered app which has edit permission on the target app.  I will post my answer later (it is quite complicated)

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you'd need to call this endpoint in MS Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-delete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http.

Though the docs seem to be missing it, you should be able to list the assignments for a user etc. by doing a GET without an assignment id.
I don't think you can guess the assignment ids, so you'll need to read them first from there.

And though it says you need delegated permissions to call the endpoint, that isn't completely true.
You can give an app the access as user permission and then login with a user and act on their behalf.
But you can also have an app do these without a user.
You can assign an administrator role to the service principal running a script, and that will allow it to do this as well.
You can do this through the Roles and administrators tab in the AAD management UI.

The only tough situation here is that this ability is only in the beta version of MS Graph API.
But Azure AD Graph API is not recommended for use.
So, you have two options right now:

1. Use the beta version of MS Graph API for this, and upgrade as soon as the API reaches a stable version

   - beta is a bit volatile, so there some risks in using it in production
2. Use Azure AD Graph API and upgrade to MS Graph API once it reaches a stable version

   - this upgrade would probably be mandatory

Comment: Thanks juunas.  Your answer is correct and very helpful.  Appreciated.